# How to MvvmCross Bind drawableId To Imageview

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How to return the `DrawableId` in a Converter?

My Layout file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgTest"
    android:src="@drawable/Img_Test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"   
    android:layout_margin="20dp"   
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    local:MvxBind ="DrawableId MySwapImage(true)" />
```

I have both images in the resources folder

1. ImgTest1.png
2. ImgTest2.png

My value Converter:

```
public class MySwapImageValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, int>
{
    protected override int Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value)
        {
            // ImgTest1
        }
        else
        {
            // ImgTest2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do something like: return Resource.Drawable.ImgTest1;

Comment: Just look at my answer to your question at following page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32090425/2653134 (sovled with string return instead of int)

Comment: @Martijn The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context is the error message I got when I use : Resource.drawable.ImgTest1  what seems to be the problem?

Comment: In the Resource.designer.cs you can see the full name of your resource file. It is something like YourAppName.UI.Droid.Resource if you use that it should work. I suspect you target the Android.Resource now.

Comment: @Martijn followed your advice. in my UI.ViewModel(Portable), I tried to add the reference, it said "adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency.  Any work around solution ?

Comment: Wait, what? You have this in your core package? That is never gona work with DrawableId. You need to add this valueconverter to your Android project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that this `Converter` shouldn't be in your `.Core` project (the one where your VMs are). This code is platform specific because it changes the boolean (something that is pertinent to your business logic) into a Drawable (something that only exists on Android). Being so, it should belong in your `.Droid` project.

In my projects I create a `Converters` folder inside the Droid project to store all my platform specific converters. The code for your `MySwapImageValueConverter` should look like this

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

using Cirrious.CrossCore.Converters;

namespace MilkBottle.Droid.Converters
{
    public class MySwapImageValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, int>
    {
        #region Methods

        protected override int Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var result = value ? Resource.Drawable.ImgTest1: Resource.Drawable.ImgTest2;
            return result;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I will follow your guide and get back here after I try.

Comment: How can I call the converter from PCL?